# ScheduledExecutorService stop runnable after shutdownNow called

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, scheduledexecutorservice

I want some help to stop my current runnable thread when I shutdown the ScheduledExecutorService. In below code I would like stop my streaming job when terminate the parent executer.

even though I use shutdownNow() its not stopping current running thread and its stream loop. I can terminate if have Thread.sleep() in DoSomeHardJob.adding() using InterruptedException.

```
scheduledFuture.cancel(true);
```

I tried the above not working. Is there any other option can I try to terminate the current job. Any help/Idea really apricated.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ThreadWork {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        
        ScheduledExecutorService schExService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(0);
        
        int repeatMin = 2;
        
         
        ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture = schExService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new RunConfiguraiton(), 0, repeatMin, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        
        Thread.sleep(3*1000);
        
        scheduledFuture.cancel(true);
        schExService.shutdownNow();
 
        
        Thread.sleep(1*1000);
        
        System.out.println("I am good there for fresh start");
        
    }

}

class RunConfiguraiton implements  Runnable
{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        
        List<Integer> intList = Arrays.asList(10,5,60,45,100,50,232);
        
        
     
         try {
            intList.stream().map(i -> {
                try {
                     return DoSomeHardJob.adding(i);
                }  catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return 0;
                }
                
             }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("final exit");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
    
    static class DoSomeHardJob{
        public static int adding(int i) throws Exception {
            try {
                int result = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < 999999999; j++) {
                    System.out.print(j);
                    result = result + j; 
                }
                
                return result;
            } 
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                 throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: your best bet is to check Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted(), not in every loop iteration, but say after a chunk of work is done.

Comment: I am not sure how efficient to check often Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted(),. in  DoSomeHardJob class. more or less i was expecting for any kind of event lister to catch Thread interrupt. @prembhaskal thanks for suggestion

Comment: You cannot listen for thread interruptions. And checking for interruptions every once and a while will have a negligible performance impact.